# CSS not showing when re-using Blazor Components in different project

Tags: c#, html, razor, components, blazor

So i wanted to create a layout component, to keep our pages standardised. So i created a simple component

But when i have added the component to a new project, i can see text, but non of the css is being pulled through.

This is my first attempt at trying to add a component to a new project, so apologies for my lack of understanding..

I thought it would be as simple as packaging the RCL to a nuget package, downloading the component library to the new project, referencing the component and off i go...

But i guess some things need to be added to the new project or i have missed something obvious..

The component is just a simple navmenu with no js or anything fancy, just css and html..

Anybody have any ideas? I haven't come across many posts on the internet for this problem.

---

FIXED - Hope this helps someone new in blazor

Comment: I still have a little issue tho, i am using an image in the component, how do i bring this to the new app, as its giving me a 404 on it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the issue -

I did not realise that you would have to reference the css files into the new web app, that you have used in the RCL - So simply adding the lines below in the host worked..

```
<link href="_content/Blazor.Components/css/HeaderAndFooter.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```